# Table header stay fixed when search element inside table

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I need some help! I use flask to create a website with data table, I tried many different methods but I don't manage to fix the table head and when I search the table head collapsed also. How can I solve it in my code please?

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxhHU.png)

HTML:

```
<div>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Country">
    </div>
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Total Cases</th>
                <th>Today Cases</th>
                <th>Total Deaths</td>
                <th>Today Deaths</th>
                <td>Total Recovered</td>
                <td>Active</td>
                <td>Critical</td>
                <td>Cases Per One Million</td>
                <td>Deaths Per One Million</td>
                <td>Total Tests</td>
                <td>Tests Per One Million</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>


    </table>
```

CSS:

```
#myTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    /* Collapse borders */
    width: 100%;
    /* Full-width */
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    /* Add a grey border */
    font-size: 18px;
    /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
    text-align: left;
    /* Left-align text */
    padding: 12px;
    /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
    /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Where did you define `myFunction();`?

Comment: Im not sure what you need... if you need to fix header to top use position:sticky

Comment: Table collapse? `border-collapse: collapse;` has something to do with iy?

Comment: function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}

Comment: Sorry I don't really now how to edit my reply but above was my original function in js and the result is the same. Table collapse is already in CSS file.

Comment: @Every Screamer please click 'my table' then you see, it should be a collapse table and when I search (ex. country) then it should have the table head fixed and the row corresponding to my search input